# Dictionary.ContainsKey Throws KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a web page using ASP.Net MVC and razor. In my cshtml file I am checking to see if a key exists in a dictionary. If the key doesn't exist, the page crashes and I get a KeyNotFoundException.

My model

```
Dictionary<string,string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>(){
 { "ValidKey", "ValidValue"}
};
```

CSHTML code

```
@if (Model.MyDictionary.ContainsKey("ValidKey")) {
  <span>@Model.MyDictionary["ValidKey"]</span>
}
@if (Model.MyDictionary.ContainsKey("InvalidKey")) {
  <span>@Model.MyDictionary["InvalidKey"]</span>
}
```

The first check works fine, but the second one crashes. I don't understand why I would get a KeyNotFoundException when trying to check for a key. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be a typo -- maybe casing? I know it sounds trivial but I see it all the time...

You could also try writing it as

```
@{ string result; }
@if (Model.MyDictionary.TryGetValue("ValidKey", out result)) {
<span>@result</span>
}
```

to avoid the possibility of duplicating the key, and the minor performance issue of doing the dictionary twice.

Comment: I can't believe this, it was a typo. The ContainsKey was using the correct key, and then when trying to access the value, i was using the key with one letter missing. I thought it was the ContainsKey all along since that was the part that was being highlighted in the error page.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: And that is why it is important to look at the documentation for a function when you think it is behaving strangely. If you were to look up ContainsKey you would see that is cannot throw a KeyNotFoundException, which would point you towards the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) ContainsKey actually never throws a KeyNotFoundException, which intuitively makes sense because the whole point of ContainsKey is to check whether or not a key exists.

Testing with my own code to try and replicate the problem didn't show any problems:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("ValidKey", "Valid Value");

string validKey = "ValidKey";
string invalidKey = "InvalidKey";

//Outputs "Valid Value"
if (dict.ContainsKey(validKey))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dict[validKey]);
}
//Outputs nothing and throws no exception
if (dict.ContainsKey(invalidKey))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dict[invalidKey]);
}
```

Note that I am setting the keys to variables to avoid the potential problems @Steve Cooper points out in his answer.

Likely what is happening for you that you are accidentally trying to access a different key than the one you actually checked for as @Steve Cooper suggests, so check for typos